# Is it possible to have a pointer point a base class created by curiously recursive template?

Tags: c++, crtp

Is it possible to have a pointer point a base class created by curiously recursive template without using an interface  ?

Example:

```
template<typename Derived>
class Base
{
public:
    Base();
    virtual ~Base();

    void EventA();
    void EventB();
    void EventC();

};

class DerivedA: public Base<DerivedA>
{
private:
    void EventA_imp();
    void EventB_imp();
    void EventC_imp();
};

class Manager
{
private:
    Base* base;
};
```

Comment: It’s not really clear what your asking.

Comment: No. There is no class `Base`.

Answer (score 3):

you cannot, `Base` is not a type, `Base<DerivedA>` is, but a pointer to `Base<DerivedA>` would not be assignable a pointer to `Base<DerivedB>`, of course.

What you can do is to derive `Base` from something else (say, `BaseTypeErased`) and have a pointer to it. A pointer to an object of type `DerivedA` could then be assigned to a `BaseTypeErased*`.

```
class BaseTypeErased{
public:
    virtual ~BaseTypeErased(){};
};

template<typename Derived>
class Base : public BaseTypeErased
{
public:
    Base(){};
    virtual ~Base(){};

};

class DerivedA: public Base<DerivedA>
{
};

int main()
{
    BaseTypeErased* base = new DerivedA;
    delete base;
}
```

This is an example of what I mean. Of course, managing the methods would be more cumbersome, as in:

```
#include <iostream>

class BaseTypeErased{
public:
    void EventA(){
        EventA_imp();
    }
    virtual ~BaseTypeErased(){}
private:
    virtual void EventA_imp() = 0;
};

template<typename Derived>
class Base : public BaseTypeErased
{
public:
    Base() : derived(static_cast<Derived&>(*this)){};
    virtual ~Base(){};
private:
    void EventA_imp() override {
      derived.EventA();
    }
    Derived& derived;
};

class DerivedA: public Base<DerivedA>
{
    public:
    void EventA() {
        std::cout << "DerivedA::EventA" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    BaseTypeErased* base = new DerivedA;
    base->EventA();
    delete base;
}
```

Comment: look like you couldn't get away with the virtual and override method as well